# Why my html appears blank when using jinja2?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have just installed VSCode to learn Flask, with all extensions needed. I was reproducing the beginner's exercise of a 'Hello, World!' html. It worked perfectly.

Then I tried to follow a To Do App Tutorial. I reproduced a html template using Jinja2, but the html opened completely blank, it seems jinja2 isn't working at all.

I installed flask in the virtual environment, the library is correctly loaded. Does anybody know what's wrong? ? Can it be a VSCode problem? I have the latest version installed in Win10.

Here are the codes:

base.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
<html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Task Master</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="content">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Task Master</h1>
    {% if tasks|length < 1 %}
    <h4 style="text-align: center">There are no tasks. Create one below!</h4>
    {% else %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Added</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ task.content }}</td>
                <td>{{ task.date_created.date() }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/delete/{{task.id}}">Delete</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="/update/{{task.id}}">Update</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="form">
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="content" id="content">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Task">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_content = request.form['content']
        new_task = Todo(content=task_content)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'There was an issue adding your task'

    else:
        tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
        return render_template('index.html', tasks=tasks)


@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    task_to_delete = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)

    try:
        db.session.delete(task_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    except:
        return 'There was a problem deleting that task'

@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update(id):
    task = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        task.content = request.form['content']

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'There was an issue updating your task'

    else:
        return render_template('update.html', task=task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Could you try adding `{% extends "base.html" %}` at the beginning of your `index.html`?

Comment: i think you need `{% extends 'base.html' %}` at the top of your index.html

Comment: I didn't realize it was missing here, but it's originally added at the beginning of the index.html code and it doesn't work.